# Update Value in the Column based on another value in the same column for different row

Tags: sql

How Could I Update A specific Value in a Column to equal another value at the same column , the difference between them a value fixed in the row  , in other words I have table of items with prices versus warehouses that the item Prices are repeated for the same Item(row) according to the warehouse, I'm looking for update the price of the item for specific warehouse based on another warehouse Price ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverlow. Please read [How to ask a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056). And mention your database, sample data and output.

Comment: @Utsav this is a theoretic question, which shows the need for a from and a join in the query, I do not think it should be limited to an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `join` with your condition to find the source record (`t2`) which will enable you to update the target record (`t1`)

```
update t1
set t1.c1 = t2.c1
from MyTable t1
join MyTable t2
on t1.c2 = 'some value' and t2.c3 = 'some other value'
```